# Magento Additional Information Attributes icon instead text

Tags: magento-1.8, product-attribute, attribute-set

I think that my question yesterday was a bit confusing, so today I'm asking again. In my magento shop I wan't to display icons instead text for product attributes. Attributes that we found under additional information, as you can see below. Code that generates attributes with corresponding values is below:

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
<tr>
    <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
    <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can replace this code:

```
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?>
```

with

```
<?php if ($_data['code'] == 'processor') : //or any other code?>
    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/attributes/processor.png')?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?>" />
<?php else : ?>
    <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

If you want to replace for all attributes, just create images with the same name as the attribute code inside the `images/attributes/` folder of your theme skin and replace

```
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?>
```

with

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/attributes/'.$_data['code'].'.png')?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?>" />
```